# Shortest pregnancy length possible using artificial womb technology

Tags: society, genetics, genetic-engineering

Let's say that genetic engineering can make a baby be born far less than 8 - 9 months and since the artificial womb is a device it would not have the metabolism limitations that a real womb have so how much shorter could pregnancy length become for a healthy baby be born? Could they be born in just three months considering the advances in Designer baby technology?

Using genetic modifications certain genes that make the fetus grow could be enhanced so the baby could grow much faster than "normal". But there would be a limit on how fast cells would divide and grow in a healthy way without losing efficiency. And the artificial womb could deliver nutrients in a efficient and programmed way that could be much better than inside the woman's womb. And the device should be equipped with some king of weak AI to know when the baby is ready to be born and delivered. Sorry if I am answering my own question.

Comment: You are giving us an underspecified math problem: in other words, you are asking us "how long does it take to walk to Tipperary, if I can move faster than walking?", but you are not telling us how faster. Is it by bike? By car? By train? By catapult?

Comment: (1) Women get pregnant. Machines don't. You probably mean the shortest time of gestation, not of pregnancy. (2) The mother does very much more than " deliver nutrients"; she also sends signals which direct the development of the embryo. (3) The development of the embryo and the fetus is very much more complicated than cells dividing. (4) All in all, nobody knows the answer. As anecdotal data points, chimpazees gestate for about eight months, and gorillas for about eight months and a half.

Comment: There is no "metabolic limit" of the womb *alone*. The foetus has limits too. You can plausibly achieve six months by stimulating the foetus (converting what would be a premature birth into a "more or less" normal birth). Much more than that... you get one stillborn or soon dead baby. E.g. the lungs start maturing at around six-seven months, and accelerating this has negative effects on the newborn's immune system (we do it all the same for premature babies, since the alternative is a dead child now).

Comment: I think the artificial womb is a medical project, not an economic project. Its design does *not* have the purpose to speed up pregnancy. It is a solution for particular medical problems that would prevent a woman from being able to give birth. There could be offspin from research, but for now, the purpose is medical. It won't be easy, to go experiment with pregnancy. It will be looked at with criticism,. I wonder if any  research will be accepted, when its only purpose is, to speed things up and get women back to the work floor earlier.

Comment: Why do you need babies to be born faster? The reason I'm asking is, artificial wombs might make gestation more successful, so even if an individual fetus doesn't grow faster you can grow the population faster.

Comment: @justforplaylists, if ever, one would use an artificial womb to make babies born more mature, instead of letting them be a eat-sleep-poop machine for several months.

Comment: This al depends on how you have altered their genes, and how many birth defects are are willing to risk, before 8 weeks major organs are missing, for a normal human defect risk  reaches its inflection point at around 28 weeks.

Comment: Voting to close as it has been pointed out by others that not only is this question unanswerable and unreasonable in its current state, but the information needed to make this answerable would require handwaving advances in medical science that are akin to handwaving the entire question. More simply, you'll have to either simply handwave the why and how of this technology, or don't use it at all if it feels like too much of a stretch in your story.

Comment: How is this question "story based"? I see nothing of plot development or character development. This reads more like a question of technology in society, which is clearly worldbuilding. I'd like see the OP edit this question to either address the social & cultural impact (why might this society choose to do this) and that's the better option; or else edit to address something of the nature of the technology itself, which might help us determine, given normal baby development in utero, a reasonable earliest date. (cont...)

Comment: (cont) --- OP, if you can choose one of those and edit accordingly (whilst taking into account the answers you've already received), I'd vote to reopen this. I'd also not mind if you asked either or both of those suggested questions separately.

Answer (score 4):

The [shortest pregnancy on record](https://www.cnn.com/2021/11/10/health/premature-baby-holds-world-record-trnd/index.html) is 21 weeks. At this point, the heart has just started beating, and a month before the lungs can take air in a [normal human development](https://doctorlib.info/physiology/illustrated/1.html).

What about better than normal human development?

Let’s try a few different models, to see what the limits look like.

Fastest model -

A human baby is at 21 weeks is 1 pound (0.45 kilograms) of mostly water (18 grams per mole). And every mole contains 602 sextillion atoms (6.02 x 10^23). Taken together, a 21 week old human baby is about 15 septillion atoms of material (25 zeroes) in the baby.

Assuming every atom was a robot that could innerantly pilot itself to its proper place, how long would it take? This model is kind of like pouring out your sugar on the table, and it landing in a perfect 3D sandcastle. The average speed of particles moving in water is 1,500 meters per second - so this could be quite fast!

Factory model -

But we know people aren’t made that way. The material is up taken into tiny cellular factories, processed, and delivered as output. These factories [limit potential inflow using osmotic differential](http://dxline.info/diseases/fetal-development) a little like a low pressure vacuum) to bring in wanted material.

Generalizing our factories to the size of a red blood cell (6 to 8 micrometers- using 6 for the calculations) and wildly guessing the osmotic conductance is 0.5 since I cannot find values online, each one of these single factories can move 14 one-trillionths of a milliliter (10^-12) per second in or out.

Let’s model our factories doing nothing but build other factories, until they get to the mass of a human being. The speed of factory inputs is really close to the “fastest” model we just looked at. How long does the factory spend doing the work?

According to [this source](https://www.remembryo.com/) the speed at which a normal human cell divides is one division per day.

Using that factory output rate,  how long will it take these factories to output a half-kilogram / half-liter (the weight of our 21 week newborn in raw cells)? 33 days.

Building model-

There’s more going than just the conversion of raw material into cellular bricks. Major restructuring is going on, and starts right about where the factory model leaves off.

First, the three separate, but intertwined specialized systems : digestion, circulation, and nervous lay themselves out as a three layer mesh called a trilaminer sheet. It’s a brilliant move that keeps them from needing to grow around or plumb some kind of “reference” human body, like you might think if you were to just look at an image of the finished product.

Then, the entire body folds itself INSIDE OUT. The dirty old factory cells that built are scaffolding are expelled, and the whole sections of the body move up the neural column and rebuild the body in much closer to its final form.

Hard to imagine a good way to convert this into numbers.

There are probably better models, but those are the ones I have.

Answer (score 1):

## A day or so

A hyper efficient womb would already have all the cells needed to make a body ready. Cells take a few hours to replicate, so a few cycles to make new cells with the correct DNA, and you can just drop the cells down in a nano machine lattice to draw them into the correct form.

You'll want to run a few cycles of replication to ensure all the DNA is working well, so a day seems reasonable for a hyper efficient womb.

Comment: this only works if you skip basically all developmental processes, thats not an artificial womb that is a high speed body printer

Comment: In the future, maybe a high speed body printer is what they mean by artificial womb.

Comment: I have to vote this down, it disregards the brain. Neural pathways cannot be assembled using mechanical means, they are electrical and millions of these pathways are developed (learned) by the foetus, during pregnancy. With only nanotubes building its body, your baby could be born with a physiologically correct brain, but given the time frame, that brain would require "supplemental programming", yielding an android robot rather than a human. A very good android, but still a robot.